# Disable Autocomplete for Specific Language Feature

Tags: c++, sublimetext2

I import `vector` from `std` using

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
```

I do this specifically so I don't have to namespace vectors for increased readability. So it is supremely annoying that the `C++` package in Sublime autocompletes to

```
std::vector<char> v;
```

Instead of just

```
vector
```

How do I disable this without disabling all autocompletion or losing C++ language support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Sublime Text 2, it's quite easy. Click on `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` to open your `Packages` folder in your operating system's file explorer. Go to the `C++` directory, delete the file named `std-vector-(v).sublime-snippet`, and you're all set.