# Disable Autocomplete for Specific Language Feature in ST3

Tags: c++, sublimetext3

I import `vector` from `std` using

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
```

I do this specifically so I don't have to namespace vectors for increased readability:

```
vector<char> v;
```

So it is supremely annoying that the `C++` package in Sublime autocompletes to

```
std::vector<char> v;
```

Instead of just

```
vector
```

How do I disable this in *Sublime Text 3* without disabling all autocompletion or losing C++ language support?

Someone had [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23435557/130427) for me on how to do it in Sublime Text 2. But it doesn't work for ST3 because the files they mention are no longer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this follows the same principle as the Sublime Text 2 answer but is slightly more involved. First, you need to install `PackageResourceViewer` via [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation):

[image]

From there, you need to `Extract Package` and choose `C++`:

[image]

This will extract the problematic file into the directory given by `Browse Packages...`:

[image]

You can't just delete it, though, because that will cause ST3 to default to the old snippet inside of its default installation. You have to *edit* the snippet and remove the `std::`, overriding the autocomplete

[image]

On the plus side, this causes the snippet to work *for* you instead of *against* you because now you can quickly edit the `vector` type and then tab to change its name, an improvement on the default autocomplete behavior:

[image]